# Absolute convergence of multi-dimensional Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For a Lipschitz function $f$ defined in $[0,2\pi]^d$ for $d>1$, is that true
that the multi-dimensional Fourier series converges absolutely?
In other words, $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^d}|\hat{f}(k)|<\infty$. Is there any reference on such results?

Answer (score 1):

I found a related paper myself:

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs13324-012-0025-6